# How to check if a WooCommerce product type is NOT variable?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, types, product

I need a code to check wether a woocommerce product type is not "variable"

To check if something IS a variable product, I usually use this:

```
if ($product->is_type('variable') ) {
// do something
}
```

But I need to check if it is NOT a variable product, so I thought I was supposed to do it this way but this results in PHP errors...

```
if (! $product->is_type('variable') ) {
// do something
}
```

EDIT: I get the following error: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_type() on null"

I thought there was something wrong with my code. But then I tested it in other template files and it worked. I wanted to use my php codition in functions.php to dequeue a style everywhere except for variable products. Like so:

```
global $product;    
if (! $product->is_type('variable') ) {
    wp_dequeue_style('sample');
}
```

So it can not be done this way? Any idea?

Comment: To help understand, could you please add the php error returned ?

Comment: Easy round about way, add the logic for not a variable in the else block.

Comment: Also, please post the php errors.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
if ( $product->get_type() !== 'variable' ){
// do something
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by that question? Can you share more details about that code? Keep in mind that a good explanation helps others to understand your answer and learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Your theme's functions.php file gets called for every page on your WP site. If you have a weak controlled function there you are veri likely going to face some fatal error all over the website. In your case all you need to do is to check if $product is indeed an instance of Wc_Product or null.

So, change your code into this:

```
global $product;    
if (!empty($product) && is_a($product,Wc_Product::class) && ! $product->is_type('variable') ) {
    wp_dequeue_style('sample');
}
```

The explanation is that we check that $product actually has a value and it is really a Wc_Product class instance. If that is ok then you check for the $product->is_type. This way you won't face fatal errors all over when you'r global $product variable has not been set yet by Woocommerce

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this error, you can try the following lightweight way:

```
if ( is_product() && ! has_term( 'variable', 'product_type', get_the_id() ) ) {
    wp_dequeue_style('sample');
}
```

Or also this heavier way:

```
if ( is_product() ) {
    global $product;
    
    if ( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
    }
    
    if ( is_a($product, 'WC_Product') && ! $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        wp_dequeue_style('sample');
    }
}
```